# How can I preserve the "move" cursor when dragging elements in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

## What is wrong?

This is the current behavior in Chrome. Notice that when the dragging starts, the cursor changes back to "default":

I have tried using the `effectAllowed` along with `dragEffect`. As well as setting the move cursor on the element itself.

[image: When dragging in Chrome, the move cursor does not persist.]

---

## Desired Behavior

Here is an example of the same code running in FireFox, it preserves the move cursor when dragging:

[image: Dragging and dropping in firefox preserves the move cursor.]

---

Here is the code I used for those examples:

How can I keep the move cursor present whenever dragging is active in Chrome?

```js
/* draggable element */
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
item.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    e.target.style.cursor = 'move';
    e.target.style.opacity = 0;
  });
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  e.target.style.cursor = '';
  e.target.style.opacity = '';
}


/* drop targets */
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
boxes.forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter)
  box.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  box.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  box.addEventListener('drop', drop);
});


function dragEnter(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}

function dragLeave(e) {}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  const draggable = document.getElementById(id);
  const box = e.target.closest('.box');
  box.appendChild(draggable);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.drop-targets {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 3px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  /* align items in the box */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.drag-over {
  border: dashed 3px red;
}

.item {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #F0DB4F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="drop-targets">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="item" id="item" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me in both FF and Chrome, I get a different icon when dragging though, it's like a hand+arrow sort of thing. Running linux though so it's probably my UA

Comment: Maybe try `* { cursor: revert }` but other than that I don't think I can help you because it's working fine for me

Comment: Thanks for the lead @ZachJensz, unfortunately, it didn't work out. That other bit is interesting that it could also be affected by the operating system (I'm on a mac).